# Why can't use the Int value from hashUnique?

Tags: haskell, monads

I want to store the value returned from hashUnique into a list, but I can't do that:

```
import Data.Unique
import Data.List as L

cnter = do
   u <- newUnique
   return (hashUnique u)

main = cnter:[]
```

It will give out the error message : `No instance for (Show (IO Int)), arising from a use of 'print' at <interative>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cnter` is an IO action that returns an Int.  That is, `cnter` has type `IO Int`.  You are trying to use it as an `Int`.  What you really want is to execute the action, obtaining the `Int`, and then use that result:

```
import Data.Unique
import Data.List as L

cnter = do
   u <- newUnique
   return (hashUnique u)

main = cnter >>= \c -> print [c]
```

Or with do notation:

```
main = do c <- cnter
          print [c]
```

But I'm not sure why you want to construct a list just to print it, I'd just `print c`, personally:

```
main = cnter >>= print
```

Comment: I am just starting to learn Haskell a week ago, not yet quite understand the IO monad stuff, but the situation here is to generate unique ids, and store them into a list. All I am doing here is just some stupid test examples, and for this case alone, all I have to know is how to turn the `(IO Int)` into `Int`, which you have shown me :)

Comment: I actually want to store every `Int` value from using the `hashUnique` into a list. The reason to be able to print the list is for debug purpose only.